# Converting a pointer-to-member type to a simple pointer type

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I have the following type, which I get with `decltype`

```cpp
QString UserInfo::*&
```

I can remove the `&` part by wrapping `decltype` with `std::remove_reference_t` but I also want to remove `UserInfo::*` part

How can I do that so I can use only `QString` type in my templates

I'm using this template in initializer list where I don't have access to solid object or this pointer to `.*` operator in `decltype`

Comment: [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) allows you to have object of type T, so `decltype(std::declval<UserInfo>().someMember)` should do the trick

Comment: @MarekR: This is a meta-programming operation on types, not values. There's no expression.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a valid object is not necessary in unevaluated contexts (like `decltype`). To exaggerate a little, you could even dereference a null pointer in there, and nothing bad would happen, since the dereference is never actually evaluated.

To create an object of a type that is not valid, but can be used in unevaluated contexts, you can use [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval).

```
template<class T>
using member_type = decltype(std::declval<UserInfo>().*std::declval<T>());
```

Comment: IMO it is bad solution since it is permanently associated with `UserInfo` so it works only with this class only. Other answers do not have this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use template specialization to extract member type:

```
template <typename MemberType>
struct member_type;

template <typename Class, typename Member>
struct member_type<Member Class::*>
{
    using type = Member;
};

template<typename T>
using member_type_t = typename member_type<T>::type;


class A
{
public:
    int b;
};

using t = member_type_t<decltype(&A::b)>;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a trait to extract the type of the member from the member function pointer:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct member_type;

template <typename C, typename T>
struct member_type<T C::*> {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
using member_type_t = typename member_type<T>::type;

struct foo {
    int bar;
};


int main()
{
    int foo::*ptr = &foo::bar;
    using T = member_type_t<decltype(ptr)>;
    static_assert( std::is_same_v<int,T>);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version using C++17 in such way that `decltype` is not needed when template is used (a bit more handy):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <auto Fp>
struct field_type;

template<typename R, typename T, R (T::*FP)>
struct field_type<FP>
{
    using type = R;
};

template<typename R, typename T, typename...Args, R (T::*FP)(Args...)>
struct field_type<FP>
{
    using type = R;
}; 

template<auto FP>
using field_type_t = typename field_type<FP>::type;


class Foo {
public:
    int x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    std::string s;
    const int cx = 0;

    Foo() = default;

    void bar() {
        std::cout << "bar\n";
    }

    int par(int z) {
        std::cout << "bar\n";
        return z;
    }
};

template<auto F, typename T>
constexpr bool test = std::is_same_v<field_type_t<F>, T>;

static_assert(test<&Foo::x,    int>,         "");
static_assert(test<&Foo::cx,   const int>,   "");
static_assert(test<&Foo::s,    std::string>, "");
static_assert(test<&Foo::y,    double>,      "");
#ifndef HIDE_PROBLEM_ON_GCC_11
static_assert(test<&Foo::bar,  void>,        "");
static_assert(test<&Foo::par,  int>,         "");
#endif
```

For some strange reason works on all compilers, but not for gcc 11.1 or newer.

https://godbolt.org/z/4e7oKbod1